# Optimization sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Help me please optimize next SQL query

```
SELECT Executor_service.*, Executor.*
FROM Executor_service
INNER JOIN Executor ON Executor.user_id = Executor_service.executor_id
LEFT JOIN Cancel ON Cancel.executor_id = Executor.user_id AND Cancel.city_id = 3538 
WHERE Cancel.order_id IS NULL
AND Executor.user_id != 236 
AND Executor_service.service_id = 511
AND Executor_service.status = 'free'
AND Executor_service.mstatus = 'work'
AND Executor_service.city_id =3538
AND Executor.balance > 0
AND Executor.status = 'free'
ORDER BY Executor.rate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This code very slow (10-15s) ->>    LEFT JOIN Cancel ON Cancel.executor_id = Executor.user_id AND Cancel.city_id = 3538

**UPDATE 1**

I am need take Executor.user_id

Table Executor is have next struct
[Executor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDVjw.png)

Table Executor_service is have next struct
[Executor_service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgNQj.png)

And table Cancel is have next struct
[Cancel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoKNi.png)

Table Executor is exist all executors in system.

Table Executor_service is exist services for every Executor, where Executor.user_id = Executor_service.executor_id

Table Cancel is exist information about canceble order (who cancel and reason)

I need to get one executor with the highest rating, not zero balance from the specified city, which performs the service according to the specified id from the Executor_service table (Executor_service.service_id).
At the same time, the Cancel table should not contain a record that the given executor was tapped for this service

**UPDATE 2**

I change

```
SELECT Executor_service.*, Executor.*
FROM Executor_service
INNER JOIN Executor ON Executor.user_id = Executor_service.executor_id
```

to

```
SELECT Executor.user_id
FROM Executor
INNER JOIN Executor_service ON Executor.user_id = Executor_service.executor_id
```

and take 3-5 sec, but this big time for query.

Comment: Use explain to find out where you need an index

Comment: Use execution plan to see where you lose your time, it will help about where you are missing an index also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly restructured the query.  I prefer to see where table "A" directly joins to "B" and "B" to "C", etc..  I also try to keep the left-side table.column on the left and right-side table.colum to the right.  Also, criteria specific to the table, I try to put directly at the join.  This helps me visualize where the conditions are and what might help when determining indexes for optimization...

```
SELECT 
      ES.*, 
      E.*
   FROM 
      Executor_service ES
         INNER JOIN Executor E
            ON ES.executor_id = E.user_id
            AND ES.status = E.status
            AND E.balance > 0
         LEFT JOIN Cancel C
            ON ES.executor_id = C.executor_id
           AND ES.City_ID = C.city_id
   WHERE 
          ES.service_id = 511
      AND ES.status = 'free'
      AND ES.mstatus = 'work'
      AND ES.city_id = 3538
      AND ES.executor_id != 236
      AND C.order_id IS NULL
   ORDER BY 
      E.rate DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

That said, there were a couple transitive relationships (if A=B and B=C, then A=C) such as your criteria on the executor's userID which is the same as the executor_service.executor_id, so I moved that into the WHERE clause at the "ES" (alias for executor_service).  Correct on left-join for your cancel code and explicitly looking for IS NULL in the where.

As for indexes, I would ensure the following to help

```
Executor_Service table -- index on (service_id, city_id, mstatus, status )
Executor table -- index on ( user_id, status, balance ).  
Cancel table -- index on ( executor_id, city_id )
```

By including the balance in the index, it makes a covering index for the query to not require going to the data pages and can get the value directly from the index.

Comment: @PiuPiu, glad it worked... what has your time been improved to.

Answer (score 0):

Try an index on:  `executor_service(city_id, service_id, status, mstatus, user_id)`.

I am guessing that the `join` keys already have indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not selecting anything from the table you plan to `LEFT JOIN`, you can omit it altogether. Using `INNER JOIN` filters your results, but `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN` doesn't, so there is no need for it:

```
  SELECT Executor_service.*, Executor.*
    FROM Executor_service
         INNER JOIN Executor ON Executor.user_id = Executor_service.executor_id
   WHERE     Executor.user_id != 236
         AND Executor_service.service_id = 511
         AND Executor_service.status = 'free'
         AND Executor_service.mstatus = 'work'
         AND Executor_service.city_id = 3538
         AND Executor.balance > 0
         AND Executor.status = 'free'
ORDER BY Executor.rate DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Look if it suits you. If you really planed to use `LEFT JOIN` on `Cancel` table than that's the way to go.

Problem with that performance optimization is that you are currently not really using `LEFT JOIN` at all. **If you really want to use LEFT JOIN you can't use that tables' column in WHERE clause. That turns that join to INNER JOIN.**

Another smaller thing: looking at your code, it's better to connect your tables `Cancel` and `Executor_service` via common `city_id` column than to write `city_id =3538` twice:

Code with those corrections is as follows (with keeping `Cancel` table in `INNER JOIN`, as it actually was before):

```
  SELECT Executor_service.*, Executor.*
    FROM Executor_service
         INNER JOIN Executor ON Executor.user_id = Executor_service.executor_id
         INNER JOIN Cancel ON Cancel.executor_id = Executor.user_id AND Cancel.city_id = Executor_service.city_id
   WHERE     Cancel.order_id IS NULL
         AND Executor.user_id != 236
         AND Executor_service.service_id = 511
         AND Executor_service.status = 'free'
         AND Executor_service.mstatus = 'work'
         AND Executor_service.city_id = 3538
         AND Executor.balance > 0
         AND Executor.status = 'free'
ORDER BY Executor.rate DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Additionally, if you wanted to user `LEFT JOIN` to filter results so that they exclude entries in `Cancel` table (as stated in comments), then you can use following code:

```
  SELECT Executor_service.*, Executor.*
    FROM Executor_service
         INNER JOIN Executor ON Executor.user_id = Executor_service.executor_id
   WHERE     Executor.user_id != 236
         AND Executor_service.service_id = 511
         AND Executor_service.status = 'free'
         AND Executor_service.mstatus = 'work'
         AND Executor_service.city_id = 3538
         AND Executor.balance > 0
         AND Executor.status = 'free'
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Cancel.order_id
                           FROM Cancel
                          WHERE Cancel.executor_id = Executor.user_id AND Cancel.city_id = Executor_service.city_id)
ORDER BY Executor.rate DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

As an alternative, you could write your query using `LEFT JOIN` (with added `Cancel.order_id` among selected values) and than move your `WHERE Cancel.order_id IS NULL` condition in outer query.

### TL;DR:

If you really wanted to use INNER JOIN on `Cancel` table than you can omit it altogether. If you wanted to use it as to exclude data connected to existing data in `Cancel` table, than you should rewrite it as posted in last code (or via subquery) . If none of those - it's hard to optimize a code without knowing data behind it... In that case I at least hope these little inputs helped you to better understand what you really want and what you're getting.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply.
I'm using LEFT JOIN because I need to check that there are no entries in the Cancel table. INNER JOIN will return an empty response

Comment: @PiuPiu if that's what you wanted to do, than you didn't write it right. The ways you wrote it would turn it into `INNER JOIN` (as I stated). I edited my answer and added another code example, referencing this.